# Creating a Bomb - Cocos2d/Box2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm still trying to figure out how to create a bomb simulation.  I have a ball and a bomb, when the ball collides with the bomb the bomb explodes and forces the ball in which ever direction the ball was thrown in.

Right now I am using ApplyLinearImpulse, but I am forced to choose a specific direction. I just need the ball to be forced in which ever direction it was thrown in.

For example,

The ball was thrown at the left top side of the bomb, then the ball is forced up and to the left.
The ball was thrown at the left bottom side of the bomb, then the ball is forced down and to the left.

Basically, it just needs to be a bomb. Could anyone tell me how to do this? I am new to Box2d.

This is what I am using right now.

```
-(void) explodeBomb
{
    b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(-20,20); // give the direction for the force.

    _ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, _ballBody->GetWorldCenter());
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the direction just be in the direction of `pos(bomb) - pos(ball)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some math there. Assuming the body's and bomb's positions are at `bodyPosition` and `bombPosition` respectively:

```
double diffX = bodyPosition.x - bombPosition.x;
double diffY = bodyPosition.y - bombPosition.y;
double distance = sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY);
double normalizedX = diffX / distance;
double normalizedY = diffY / distance;
```

Now assuming you want to apply a force of `20` units:

```
float factor = 20.0f;
b2Vec2 force(normalizedX * factor, normalizedY * factor);
_ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, _ballBody->GetWorldCenter());
```

Comment: Don't take this weird but I love you lol. Could you please explain to me what you just did because that is EXACTLY what I was talking about.

Comment: @Jon: Basically the first block of code above calculates the normalized vector for the direction, while the second block of code scales up the normalized vector based on the force you want to apply. p/s: normalized vector is the vector with length of 1 unit